# How can I indentify a object in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

```
/* Dialog Class */
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    //void displayDialog(QString arg);    //外界字符串传入到textEdit中

    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

/* MainWindow.cpp */
Dialog *dlg = new Dialog;
Dialog *dlg2 = new Dialog;
```

I create two object based on Dialog Class, how can I indentify these two Dialog if I don't know the variable *dlg and *dlg2?

Comment: How you want to create them without assigning them to a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of identifying any `QObject` is by using `Qobject`'s [`objectName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property.

This is very commonly used in testing, and we can see it as the primary form of identification used in [`findChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) and [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren).

**EDIT:**

So generally speaking all your objects are going to be owned by a main window. This allows Qt to handle a lot of things for you. A few quick examples of how this is important:

1. If I destroy my main window all my children will also be destroyed, so I won't have popups hanging out after my main window closes
2. Poping up a window will steal focus from the main window, and if it's a blocking dialog it will prevent anything else in it's current hierarchy from being activated
3. Obviously finding things is important here too

Please note that all these features function through the entire hierarchy. That is to say, if I have a `QObject` that's a owned by a `QDialog` that's owned by the main window, this `QObject` will be destroyed when the main window is, will steal focus from other objects in the hierarchy, and can be found by searching starting at the main window.

Rather than 2 unassociated popups, lets make 2 popups that are owned by a main window:

```
QMainWindow mainWin;
QDialog dlg(&mainWin);
QDialog dlg2(&mainWin);

dlg.setObjectName("two");

QDialog* dfind = mainWin.findChild<QDialog*>("two");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but I tried this way:
`Dialog *dlg = new Dialog;
Dialog *dlg2 = new Dialog;
dlg2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("two"));

Dialog *dfind = this->findChild<Dialog *>("two");`

then the error is "findSubDialog.exe has stop working"

Comment: @Amor_aeternus If you want to use `findChild` you have to make the dialogs children of your main window: `Dialog *dlg = new Dialog(this);` Without this `dfind` will be `NULL` and your app will crash if you try to use it.

Comment: @Amor_aeternus Your design of 2 `QDialog`s without a common owner is problematic at best. I've updated my answer with a few of the key reasons that a well designed Qt program will always have a singular `QObject` which directly or indirectly owns all other `QObject`s in the program. I've also demonstrated how finding would work in a well designed Qt program. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your dialogs does not have any parents (parent == nullptr) like in your example, you can iterate over all windows and compare it's object name.

```
QWidget* GetWidgetByObjectName(const QString& Name) {
    QGuiApplication* a = dynamic_cast<QGuiApplication*>(QCoreApplication::instance());
    if (a) {
        for (QWidget* w : a->allWidgets()) {
            if (w->objectName() == Name) {
                return w;
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
QDialog* Dlg = qobject_cast<QDialog*>(GetWidgetByObjectName("two"));
```

However, in most cases it is better to assign a parent. In this case you could iterate over all your children as already posted here.